# Prove that $\big\||A||A^*|\big\|=\big\|A^2\big\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a complex Hilbert space $E$.

> Why $\big\||A||A^*|\big\|=\big\|A^2\big\|$? where $|X|=(X^*X)^{1/2}$.

Comment: You've been around the block long enough to know that this is not yet a [good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\xi\in E$. We have the following observation:
$$\||A|\cdot|A^*|\xi\|^2=\langle|A|\cdot|A^*|\xi,|A|\cdot|A^*|\xi\rangle=\langle|A^*|\xi,|A|^2|A^*|\xi\rangle=\langle|A^*|\xi,A^*A|A^*|\xi\rangle=$$
$$\langle A|A^*|\xi,A|A^*|\xi\rangle=\|A|A^*|\xi\|^2 $$
and from this it follows that $\||A|\cdot|A^*|\|=\|A\cdot|A^*|\|$. Since $B(H)$ is a $C^*$-algebra, we have $\|T\|^2=\|TT^*\|$ for all $T\in B(H)$, so applying this at the second and second-to-last equalities, we have
$$\||A|\cdot|A^*|\|=\|A|A^*|\|=\|A|A^*|^2A^*\|^{1/2}=\|AAA^*A^*\|^{1/2}=\|(A^2)(A^2)^*\|^{1/2}=(\|A^2\|^2)^{1/2}=\|A^2\|$$

Answer (score 0):

We can apply the polar decomposition $$A=U|A|,\qquad A^*=V|A^*|$$ where $U$ and $V$ are partial isometries, isometric on ${\rm Im}\,|A|$ and ${\rm Im}\,|A^*|,$ respectively. Then $$\displaylines{\|A^2\|=\|U|A||A^*|V^*\| \\ =\||A||A^*|V^*\| =\|V|A^*||A|\|\\=\||A^*||A|\|=\||A||A^*|\|}$$